# python manage.py runserver not working or showing errors

Tags: python, django, migrate

Ive set up django on a virtual env and im trying to run it. I've made sure that python is installed and that my virtual env is activated. I created a django project "my_site" with the command django-admin startproject my_site . The virtual env is "my_env"
This is my project directory:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxlwA.png)
In the command terminal when i run python migrate.py runserver nothing happens, the server crashes with no error message and i am not able to access localhost 8000

```
(my_env) PS C:\Users\Ananya\OneDrive\Desktop\django> python manage.py runserver
          Watching for file changes with StatReloader
          Performing system checks...
          System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
(my_env) PS C:\Users\Ananya\OneDrive\Desktop\django>
```

This is the output for pip list :

```
(my_env) PS C:\Users\Ananya\OneDrive\Desktop\django> pip list
Package            Version
------------------ -------
asgiref            3.7.2
backports.zoneinfo 0.2.1
Django             4.2.8
pip                20.2.3
setuptools         49.2.1
sqlparse           0.4.4
typing-extensions  4.9.0
tzdata             2023.4
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.3; however, version 23.3.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\ananya\onedrive\desktop\django\my_env\scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.        
(my_env) PS C:\Users\Ananya\OneDrive\Desktop\django>
```

This is the output for pip show Django :

```
(my_env) PS C:\Users\Ananya\OneDrive\Desktop\django> pip show django
Name: Django
Version: 4.2.8
Summary: A high-level Python web framework that encourages rapid development and clean, pragmatic design.
Home-page: https://www.djangoproject.com/
Author: Django Software Foundation
Author-email: foundation@djangoproject.com
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: c:\users\ananya\onedrive\desktop\django\my_env\lib\site-packages
Requires: sqlparse, asgiref, backports.zoneinfo, tzdata
Required-by:
(my_env) PS C:\Users\Ananya\OneDrive\Desktop\django>
```

This is my python and django version

```
(my_env) PS C:\Users\Ananya\OneDrive\Desktop\django> python --version
Python 3.8.8
(my_env) PS C:\Users\Ananya\OneDrive\Desktop\django> python -m django --version
4.2.8
```

I tried running :
`python C:\Users\Ananya\OneDrive\Desktop\django\manage.py runserver` , I tried deleting and creating a new env . i was expecting the terminal output to be something like : [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzjI5.png)
where i can be directed to localhost 8000

Comment: Can you show full folder structure.

Comment: Don't post code and logs as images. Just post them using code blocks in post question form.

Answer (score 0):

Don't move folders manually in django projects. (unless your know what you are doing)

Your folder structure should be like this.

```
Env
   Django_project_name
   (terminal should move in to this folder) 

       manage.py
       sqlite.db
       Django_project_name
           settings.py
           urls.py
```

Your terminal should move in to "my_site" folder.

Run

```
cd my_site
```

Then run "migrations" and "runserver".

**Only creat project command can run outside, All the other django commands should run inside your django project folder, where manage.py file is.**
Use

```
cd my_site
```

To change the terminal location.

**So below is the normal procedure.**

1. Run create project command
2. Move into project folder / **you must move it to this folder using "cd project_name"**
3. Run migrations
4. Run server
5. **try accessing** 127.0.0.1:8000     **in your browser**

**use**

python manage.py runserver

or

python3 manage.py runserver

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256426/discussion-on-answer-by-pycm-python-manage-py-runserver-not-working-or-showing-e); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have pressed Ctrl + C while copying localhost, the server will terminate.

Answer (score 0):

So i resolved the error by simply deleting python and anaconda and re installing python